# Parsing Cisco Output in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to interpret the following output from a switch. Basically I want it to go through the output until it finds "notconnect" then store the name of the interface in an array. Then continue on through the file and store the next "notconnect" interface as the next element in the array. The interface in the following example would be Gi1/0/4. I'm just not really sure where to start with this. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Python 3.3.2.

```
b'\r\n\r\nMS-2673-DC-CS01#terminal length 0\r\nMS-2673-DC-CS01#sh interface status\r\n\r\nPort      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type\r\nGi1/0/1   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseSX SFP\r\nGi1/0/2   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseSX SFP\r\nGi1/0/3   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseSX SFP\r\nGi1/0/4                      notconnect   trunk        auto   auto Not Present\r\nGi1/0/5   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseSX SFP\r\nGi1/0/6   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP\r\nGi1/0/7   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP\r\nGi1/0/8   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP\r\nGi1/0/9   Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP\r\nGi1/0/10  Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP\r\nGi1/0/11  Connection to MS-2 connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP\r\nGi1/0/12  Connection Server  connected    32         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP\r\nMS-2673-DC-CS01#exit\r\n'
```

Comment: Seems like a regular expression would be in order, no?

Comment: I feel like i can find the "notconnect" string, but how do I go back and get the Gi1/0/4 that preceded it? Sometimes it might be Gi1/4 or Fa0/2 or Gi1/1/24...

Comment: A regexp doesn't seem like the best way to parse a fixed-column-width table…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to figure out what the format *is*. Then you can write code to parse it.

Clearly, this is a fixed-width-column format. The interface is always in the first 10 characters, the connection string in the next 20 characters, etc. So, given a line:

```
components = (line[:10], line[10:29], line[29:42], line[42:53], line[53:60],
              line[60:67], line[67:])
```

… will get the columns.

So, just loop over the lines, split each one into columns, and find the right ones:

```
def parse_log(log)
    for line in log.splitlines():
        if line[29:42].rstrip() == 'notconnect':
            yield line[:10].rstrip()

notconnect_interfaces = list(parse_log(log))
```

If you want something more general, just write a column-splitting function that takes a line and a sequence of column boundaries.

```
def parse_line(line, columns):
    for start, stop in zip(columns, columns[1:])
        yield line[start, stop].rstrip()

def parse_log(log):
    for line in log.splitlines():
        yield list(parse_line(line, (0, 10, 29, 42, 53, 60, 67, 80)))

def find_notconnected(log):
    for port, name, status, vlan, duplex, speed, type in parse_log(log):
        if status == 'notconnect':
            yield port
```

You can also just turn this into a sequence of genexprs instead of a set of functions. A little more concise, but maybe not as readable:

```
bounds = (0, 10, 29, 42, 53, 60, 67, 80)
columns = ([line[start:stop].rstrip() for start, stop in zip(bounds, bounds[1:])]
           for line in log.splitlines())
notconnected = (port for port, _, status, _, _, _, _ in columns 
                if status == 'notconnected')
```

Comment: That seems like it will do what I want it to do, but it is outputting the entire thing in one long line with a whole bunch of \r\n in-between each "line". How would I separate them into separate "lines"? Would doing a log.encode('ascii') work?

Comment: @Sumico: I haven't written any code that outputs anything, just code that gets you a list of interfaces. If you want to print them one on each line, you can just `print('\n'.join(notconnect_interfaces))`, or `for interface in parse_log(log): print(interface)` or whatever.

Comment: @Sumico: Or, if you're asking how you split the _input_ into lines… that's what the `splitlines` function does.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I was asking how to split the input into lines.